# Multiplication of two complex numbers in exponential form

Tags: complex-numbers

I am trying to understand how the multiplication of 2 complex numbers work.

I don't understand how i should behave when there are complex exponentials with different signs.

Here i've created an example in which there are both cases.

$$(e^{i600πt} - e^{-i600πt})(e^{i400πt} + e^{-i400πt})$$

What would the result of $(e^{-i600πt})(e^{i400πt})$ be?

Thanks!

Comment: Like all other exponents: $\mathrm e^{-200i\pi t}$.

Comment: Just add the exponents with the usual rules. $-600 + 400 = -200$.

Comment: Why would the signs being different make any difference? Just add them.  Like you always do.  Or add $2\pi$ to the negative one and make it positive if that makes you feel better.

Answer (score 1):

$(e^{-i600πt})(e^{i400πt})=e^{i(-600+400)πt}=e^{-200i\pi t}=\cos{({-200\pi t})}+i\sin{({-200\pi t})}$